# Java Records (JEP359) as Spring Controller Request and Response DTOs

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-14, java-record

I'm just experimenting with these new Java Records and I'm wondering if I could use them as DTOs for my request / response types in a spring boot application.

Therefore I just modified some code (class with a lot of boilerplate getter/setter to records), compiled and started my application. Trying some rest endpoints and all I got was an exception telling me:

`No serializer found for class x.y.CreateNewShopListeCommand$Item and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`

Well, ok, records do not create 'get'prefixed getter methods. Now I wonder: is it possible to use records as request / response types for spring boot controller?

EDIT: Sample Application (https://github.com/kaipaysen/playground-jdk14-records-as-dto)

```java
// HelloController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    
    public record HelloRequest(
        @JsonProperty("name") String name
    ) {}

    public record HelloResponse(
        @JsonProperty("message") String message
    ) {}

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HelloResponse hello(@RequestBody @Valid HelloRequest query) {
        return new HelloResponse("Hello " + query.name());
    }
    
}
```

Calling `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"Max"}' http://localhost:8080/hello` returns `{"message":"Hello null"}`. Debugging `hello` reveals that the Request is not properly deserialized. Any ideas on that spot?

EDIT#2:
Just found this issue [Support for JDK 14 record types #2709](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2709) in the FasterXML repo. They are working on it for jackson 2.12.

Comment: As [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-14-records-for-spring-devs) suggests, see if adding `@JsonProperty` could help.

Comment: Well, it did the trick for serializing but not for deserializing. I added a minimal sample above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this class level annotation to yours records.

`@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)`

In the jackson version 1.12 it should be available without annotation.

I think this's a bug in Jackson, You need to add a second field to your record because it doesn't work for the record which has only one field.

Comment: I tried adding the annotation like this: 
`@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    public record HelloRequest(
        @JsonProperty("name") String name
    ) {}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: try to remove @JsonProperty("name")

Comment: Still the same. Would you mind sharing a working example?

Comment: I think this's a bug in Jackson, You need to add a second field to your record. It doesn't work for record which has only one field.

Comment: Artem, you're right. Adding a second field to my HelloRequest enables deserialisation (even without annotations). The annotation in the HelloResponse is still required otherwise we'll get a "No converter found" error.

Comment: @Artem do you have a link to the Jackson bug?