# JsonProperty for Java Records in Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, java-record

I try to use Java records in Spring Boot controller with `@JsonProperty` annotation but Jackson does not bind values to record fields.

[Example](https://github.com/dimon4ezzz/spring-boot-records-demo):

```java
public record SimpleQuery(
       @JsonProperty("simple_text") String text
) {}

@RestController
public class SimpleController {
    @GetMapping
    public String get(SimpleQuery query) {
        return query.text();
    }
}
```

I would like to call `/?simple_text=test`, but it only gets `/?text=test`. Please, help me to resolve this problem on Spring Boot 2.6.6 (Java 17).

Additional:

- I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712187), it doesn't help

**UPD:**
It works great with `@PostRequest`+`@RequestBody`:

```java
@RestController
public class SimpleController {
    @PostMapping
    public String get(@RequestBody SimpleQuery query) {
        return query.text();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Spring MVC / Jackson) Mapping query parameters to @ModelAttribute: LOWERCASE\_WITH\_UNDERSCORE to SNAKE\_CASE fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503977/spring-mvc-jackson-mapping-query-parameters-to-modelattribute-lowercase-wi)

Comment: @Matthias do you suggest me add `mapper.convertValue(query)`? it doesn't work with empty params

Comment: I'd like to get simple code without additional calls

Answer (score 0):

This should work even when url has no request parameters (SpringBoot 2.6.6, Java 17):

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static record SimpleQuery(@JsonProperty("simple_text") String text) {}

    @GetMapping
    public String get(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map) {
        SimpleQuery query = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(map, SimpleQuery.class);
        return query.text();
    }
```